# Lyapunov-like function with V(0)>0

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

I am trying better understand the description of a Lyapunov function.  Say we're considering the definition of asymptotic stability of the equilibrium point $x=0$ for the system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ (abbreviated version of Theorem 4.1 from Khalil):

If $V(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function with 
\begin{equation}
V(0) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V(x) > 0 \text{ for }x\ne0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{V}(x) \le 0
\end{equation}
then $x=0$ is stable. If additionally
\begin{equation}
\dot{V}(x) < 0 \text{ for }x\ne0
\end{equation}
then $x=0$ is asymptotically stable.

I am curious to know what the implication of replacing $V(0)=0$ with $V(0)>0$ in the above statement would be.  This certainly seems problematic from an energy storage perspective.  As an example, what could be said about $x=0$ using 
\begin{equation}
V(x)=x^TPx+c^2
\end{equation}
where $P>0$ and $c$ is a positive constant?

Edit: Trying out the suggest shift

Starting from $V(x)=x^TPx+c^2$, rewrite as
\begin{equation}
V(\bar{x}) = \bar{x}^2
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = (x^TPx+c^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
so that V(0)=0. Taking the derivative
\begin{align}
\dot{V}(\bar{x}) &= 2\bar{x}\dot{\bar{x}} \\
&=2\bar{x}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(x^TPx+c^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(2x^TP\dot{x}\right)\right] \\
&= 2x^TP\dot{x}.
\end{align}
Then say that $\dot{x}$ is such that 
\begin{equation}
\dot{V}(\bar{x}) \le -x^TQx
\end{equation}
with $Q>0$. Is it correct to say that $\dot{V}(\bar{x})\le0$ from here?  I can't claim that $\dot{V}(\bar{x})<0$ since it's clear that $\dot{V}(\bar{x})=0$ when $x=0$. It is not actually even possible for $\bar{x}=0$.  Regardless, does this imply $\bar{x}$ is stable and thus $x$ is stable due to their relationship?

Comment: The relevant bound on $V(x)$ just becomes $V(x)>V(0)$ so without loss of generality we shift to make $V(0)=0$.

Comment: If $Q$ is positive definite then $-x^T Q x<0$ for $x \neq 0$, which is what you want to see for stability. (You also did your shift wrong anyway. You should have just looked at $\overline{V}(x)=V(x)-c^2$, shifting in the $V$ domain not the $x$ domain).